# Optional parameter of at UriTemplate causes twice invoces of AfterReceiveRequest - WCF - IDispatchMessageInspector

Tags: c#, wcf, http-headers, redirect, uritemplate

I just dived a little deeper into it and discovered new details.

Not the 'UriTemplate' in general causes the 2nd invocation of 'AfterReceiveRequest' but the optional parameter within!

If I call the method by

> http:/ /myserver/result/val1

AfterReceiveRequest will be invoked twice.

If I pass all possible parameters like

> http:/ /myserver/result/val1/val2/val3

there will be no useless invocation. Is that behavior as intended?

```
UriTemplate = "result/{para1=null}/{para2=null}/{para3=null}"
```

---

--- following the initial post, just for information ---

While implementing a WCF REST Service System I stuck on a problem with the http-headers.

In my `ServiceContract` there is a method with an `UriTemplate` definition at the `WebGet` attribute, so it can be called via

```
http://server/resource/val1/val2 ...
```

instead of

```
http://server/resource?para1=val1&para2=val2 ...
```

(I need this because of compatibility reasons.)

Also there is a significant value in the **http-headers** collection, that I need to read. Therefore I implement `IDispatchMessageInspector` and add this inspector to the `EndpointDispatchers` `MessageInspectors` collection. By that the `AfterReceiveRequest` will be invoked by WCF and I can access `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers` to read the desired Value.

#### The Problem:

WCF solves the `UriTemplate`-mapping by generating a second request to the destination method, but does not pass the header entries from the original call to the generated second call. So `AfterReceiveRequest` (and of course `BeforeSendReply`, too) will be invoked twice, but the header-values from the real client call are only included in the first call.

Also I found no way to correlate the first and the second `AfterReceiveRequest` call, to implement a "special way" for passing the header-value from the first to the second call.

Is there a way to tell WCF to route the headers to the `UriTemplate`-redirected second call?

Here are some code fragments to make it clear:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "result/{para1=null}/{para2=null}/{para3=null}")]
    bool MyMethod(string para1, string para2, string para3);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
[MyServiceInspectorBeavior]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public bool MyMethod(string para1, string para2, string para3)
    {
        return DoTheWork();
    }
    //...
}

public class MyServiceInspectorBeavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (EndpointDispatcher epDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers.OfType<ChannelDispatcher>().SelectMany(cDispatcher => cDispatcher.Endpoints))
        {
            epDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyInspector());
        }
    }

    //...
}

public class MyInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    //this is invoked twice for each client request, 
    //but only at the first call the header is present...
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        WebHeaderCollection webOpContext = 
                      WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers;
        string xForwardedIp = webOpContext["X-FORWARDED-IP"];
        WriteLog(xForwardedIp);

        return OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["ActivityId"];
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: No idea to solve this problem? Is it the wrong way at all, to take this approach?